# How to find major customers of particular worldwide public company (Introductions)?

Tags: professionalism, communication, management, company-culture, entrepreneurship

I was trying to get in touch with best possible corporate law firms - the local ones in the same country as where target public company is. The goal was to ask a law firm to introduce me and our own company to the target company. Based on very well established local brand name of law firm, I was expecting high possibility of instant "listen and agree" effect on the board of directors side of public company so their member or someone else would get in touch with me to request the major value we can add to them. But law firms are declining that idea so I would like to try with public companies' largest customers. How could I find those customers (the names)? I attempted google research on " largest customers" but did not find the names. I also tried to get in touch with the target public company on my own but always getting declined by either CFO's assistant, head of Investor Relations department or just about anyone else who is as close as possible to the board of directors (C level). The main reason is lack of trust. They decide to rather decline me than even read and discuss the value our company is committed to add to them so they could save time on that, thinking my phone call (and email) is from stranger, surely that stranger is a waste of time.

When being declined by particular company for the first time, it's impossible, due to the nature of our value we are committed to add, to reopen the deal. So being declined only once is "game over" for that target company. I'm afraid of losing to many potential good deals just because of doing the contact with target company on my own. I was having a lot of hopes on corporate law firms with top quality brand names but its not working. All the time I'm getting responses from attorneys they cannot do this. How could I find the target public company's largest customers so I could contact them and ask them if they could contact the target company?

Comment: this is usually done by sending random spam to any email address you can find

Comment: This would, and does, sound like some type of scam and most companies are going to turn a cold shoulder to your advances. Why aren't you just approaching the target company directly?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about how to sell a service, rather than how to navigate within a workplace

Answer (score 5):

> How could I find the target public company's largest customers so I could contact them and ask them if they could contact the target company?

So you're looking to leverage a pre-existing relationship between your "Target" company and one of their large customers to get yourself a deal with the Target. Which is not, in of itself completely ridiculous.

What **is** completely ridiculous however is that you don't even have a relationship with these customers but instead intend to cold-call them and ask them to pitch on your behalf to your actual target company.

Honestly the fact that you don't know how to find these customer companies is the least of your problems. No company or individual with a relationship worth leveraging is going to use that for a stranger, the very idea is, frankly, laughable.

> I also tried to get in touch with the target public company on my own but always getting declined by either CFO's assistant, head of Investor Relations department or just about anyone else who is as close as possible to the board of directors (C level). The main reason is lack of trust. They decide to rather decline me than even read and discuss the value our company is committed to add to them so they could save time on that, thinking my phone call (and email) is from stranger, surely that stranger is a waste of time.

What you have to understand is that it's part of these people's jobs to act as a filter - only passing things on to the C-suite that they will want to hear about. Obviously there's varying levels of competence at play but a good amount of these people are pretty good at it. If your pitch can't convince the people who you are talking to to even pass it on I don't think you're going have much more success at convincing a board member to actually take it up.

> When being declined by particular company for the first time, it's impossible, due to the nature of our value we are committed to add, to reopen the deal.

*Really?* Something legitimate that operates this way is difficult to imagine. Sounds shadier than a very shady thing to me.

Answer (score 3):

What you ask is against all logic. You want a company "Cabc" to reveal its biggest customers, so you can contact the customers, completely bypassing "Cabc" ...

The list of customers is, quite often, a very important trade secret. Disclosing such information without permission is most likely illegal. Therefore, no sane individual (lawyer or otherwise) would disclose such information.

I have no idea what business you conduct, or what is the business model you implement, but the request you have expressed in the question is at least strange, and at that level of business, it is even offending.

---

The only feasible workaround I see is the following. You hire the company "Cabc" to conduct some business with their customers for your benefit, without them disclosing their customers. If your request is reasonable, and if the payment is reasonable, they might be persuaded to accept.

---

> The main reason is lack of trust.

What did you do to increase your level of being trusted? Words like "the value our company is committed to add" are surely empty.

Ask yourself what you would do if the roles were reversed. Someone comes to you asking to hand over your most important customers to them, claiming that "they will add value". Would you jump in head first?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Why would the intermediaries you're targeting show any more "willingness to listen and agree" than your target companies? They have nothing to gain from going along with this.

Think about it from their perspective: would *you* recommend someone who you didn't even know to one of your vendors?

To put it bluntly, why should they care whether you sell your services or not? They have absolutely nothing to gain by making the introduction, and potentially a lot to lose.

Also:

> The main reason is lack of trust.

Again, why *would* they trust you? If you were in their role, would you trust a random stranger that cold-called you? Trust is something that's built over time, not established just because you need it in order to make a sale.